# array in my js file is not converting into JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I am practicing code in node.js. I want to convert my array items into JSON format. I have also try body-parser but can't succeed.

```
var express=require('express');
var app= express();
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

var items = [
{"id":"sd223",
"text":"food1"},

{"id":"sd12223",
"text":"food2"},

{"id":"s4d223",
"text":"food3"},

{"id":"s65d223",
"text":"food4"},

];

app.get('/',function(request,response)
{
    response.send(items);
});

app.listen(3000,function(){

    console.log("server 3000");
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'json format'?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the respond as `json` use `response.json(items)`. If you simply want to convert it to JSON string use `JSON.stringify(items)`

Answer (score 0):

**body-parser** is an npm module for parsing incoming **request** bodies.
If you would like to send your **response** as JSON, use `response.json(items)` as mentioned in another answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
response.header("Content-Type", 'application/json');
response.send(JSON.stringify(items, null, 4));
```